# Browser based self hosted scrum poker tool

Tags: node.js, scrum

I'm pretty happy with https://hatjitsu.toolforge.org/56180, but behind corporate firewall it doesnt work well, so i thought about self-hosting it.
I'm a complete node.js noob, when i cloned it from github and faced https://github.com/richarcher/Hatjitsu/issues/35 i'm completely lost.

I see several options

- fiddle out how to fix the issue above (uh..)
- find a similar tool (no account, simple voting, vote visualization & average calculation, free, ...) that either works behind firewall or that i can easily self-host
- ??

Any advice / help is appreciated,
br Johann

Comment: Could you add a view details to the issues you are facing?
Alternatively, I can recommend this tool developed by one of my colleagues:
https://justplanningpoker.com/